# I can't figure out what the error is, Error: Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, slider, uncaught-reference-error

I can't figure out what the error is (Error: Uncaught ReferenceError)

> (slidesWrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper)) - at slider

```
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(slide),
    slider = document.querySelector(container),
    prev = document.querySelector(prevArrow),
    next = document.querySelector(nextArrow),
    total = document.querySelector(totalCounter),
    current = document.querySelector(currentCounter);
  (slidesWrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper));
    (width = window.getComputedStyle(slidesWrapper).width);
    (slideField = document.querySelector(field));
```

The data is exported to another document

> Uncaught ReferenceError: slidesWrapper is not defined

```
slider({
    container: ".offer__slider",
    slide: ".offer__slide",
    nextArrow: ".offer__slider-next",
    prevArrow: ".offer__slider-prev",
    totalCounter: "#total",
    currentCounter: "#current",
    wrapper: ".offer__slider-wrapper",
    field: ".offer__slider-inner"
  });
```

Comment: Why the brackets? `(slidesWrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper));`

Comment: Possibly because you didn't put `const` or `let` in front of it. So you are assigning a value to a variable that has not been declared. Javascript probably allows you to do this and will implicitly declare `slidesWrapper` as a global, but Typescript would complain and wouldn't allow that. And yes indeed, why the parenthesis?

Comment: JS in strict mode doesn’t allow undeclared variable assignments. Why did you change the syntax of declaring variables halfway through, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining multiple variables with a single `const` where each variable is seperated by a comma.

This is what the code should be:

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(slide),
    slider = document.querySelector(container),
    prev = document.querySelector(prevArrow),
    next = document.querySelector(nextArrow),
    total = document.querySelector(totalCounter),
    current = document.querySelector(currentCounter,
    slidesWrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper),
    width = window.getComputedStyle(slidesWrapper).width,
    slideField = document.querySelector(field);
```

Comment: Without the comma, the var is just declared in global scope so should still be available if not strict mode